# Dynamic jQuery Smooth Scroll to Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code snippet from the W3 schools that creates a smooth scroll function to anchor tags within a page. It does this dynamically by looking for anchors that have hashes in it, and I would like to keep it this way without having to add classes etc. The issue I'm experiencing is when the script appends the URL to include the anchor id, it breaks the top offset. How can I append this code to prevent that from happening?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top-125
            }, 1000, 
            function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } 
    });
});
```